# Chamar no PHP o arquivo JasperReports com base de dados Oracle

Tags: php, codeigniter, oracle, jasper-reports

Tenho alguns arquivos gerados pelo JasperReports (.jrxml) que consultando uma base de dados Oracle. Minha dúvida está na execução direta com parametrizada no PHP (framework codeigniter), padrão MVC.

Já tentei alguns XML's, mas sem sucesso. Preciso gerar um PDF desses arquivos já criados.

Comment: Existem algumas bibliotecas. Nunca fiz o que está precisando mas essa biblioteca parece bem intuitiva: https://github.com/cossou/JasperPHP

Você pode instalar utilizando o composer e usar tranquilamente

Comment: @TurqSpl estou tentando apenas codificar no PHP a chamado do relatório JasperReports criado. Tenho salvei o relatório na pasta \report e gostaria apenas de chamar através do button no formato PDF.